# EMGUCV fastest set pixel

Tags: c#, emgucv

I Need fastest way to iterate an EmguCV bitmap matrix and set pixel. i found this after google but it takes about 3 sec for 700x500 image:

Documents says that access (get) data matrix is just o(1) but its not clearly declare about set data.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < img.Rows ; i++)

        for(int j = 0; j < img.Cols; j++){

            img.Data[x,y,0] = 255;

            img.Data[x,y,1] = 255;

            img.Data[x,y,2] = 255;

        }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The getter for `Emgu.CV.Image<>`'s `Data` property returns a reference to the three-dimension array that is used internally by the class.  When you assign to an element of that array (as you are doing in the code above) you are not calling the setter for the `Data` property, you are manipulating the array itself.

I suspect that the slowdown you are experiencing is related to calling unmanaged code, since the EmguCV code is largely unmanaged.

Try this and see if there is any change in speed:

```
Byte[,,] data = img.Data;
int rows = img.Rows;
int cols = img.Cols;

for (int y = 0; y < rows; ++i)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < cols; ++x)
    {
        data[x, y, 0] = 255;
        data[x, y, 1] = 255;
        data[x, y, 2] = 255;
    }
}
```

Also the `Image` class has a method `SetValue` that sets every pixel to a specific value.  If what you are trying to achieve is to clear the image to white, try calling `img.SetValue(new Rgb(255,255,255))` (or whichever color type you're using for the image) instead of doing it manually.  May be quicker.

Comment: just a little bit faster. it saves about 1 sec.

Comment: Ok, so the 700x500x3 = 1.05 million invocations of the `Data` property were having an effect, but not much of one.  Did you try `img.SetValue`?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < cols; x++)
    {
        b = (int)frameClone.Data[y, x, 0];
        g = (int)frameClone.Data[y, x, 1];
        r = (int)frameClone.Data[y, x, 2];
    }

    currIntensity = b + g + r;
}
```

Comment: its true y is first element and x is second

Answer (score 1):

It is much faster to convert your `Emgu.Cv.Image` to `System.Drawing.Bitmap` and iterate through the bitmap, either using safe or unsafe method.

- The safe method uses

  ```
  color.toargb = bmp.getpixel(X, Y).toargb / bmp.setpixel(X, Y).toargb
  ```

  and it is fairly straight forward.
- The unsafe method is super fast, relies on `bmp.lockbits(bmp_data)` and `interopservices.marshal` to copy bmp data to array. You can find tons of examples online.

I am very disappointed with EmguCV 3.0 pixel access.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method I use to replace color, it replaces any color given that is not within a given (difference) to the desired one. Its very fast, uses unsafe

```
/// <summary>
    /// Replaces a given color in a bitmap
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="image"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static unsafe void ReplaceColor(Bitmap image,
        Color FindColor,
        int WithinDistance,
        Color ReplaceColor
        )
    {

        byte FindColorR = (byte)FindColor.R;
        byte FindColorG = (byte)FindColor.G;
        byte FindColorB = (byte)FindColor.B;

        byte ReplaceColorR = (byte)ReplaceColor.R;
        byte ReplaceColorG = (byte)ReplaceColor.G;
        byte ReplaceColorB = (byte)ReplaceColor.B;

        byte WithinDistanceByte = (byte)WithinDistance;


        BitmapData imageData = image.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height),
            ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
            PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);



        int bytesPerPixel = 3;
        byte* scan0 = (byte*)imageData.Scan0.ToPointer();
        int stride = imageData.Stride;
        PixelData NewData = new PixelData(image.Height,image.Size);
        for (int y = 0; y < imageData.Height; y++)
        {
            byte* row = scan0 + (y * stride);
            for (int x = 0; x < imageData.Width; x++)
            {
                int bIndex = x * bytesPerPixel;
                int gIndex = bIndex + 1;
                int rIndex = bIndex + 2;

                byte pixelR = row[rIndex];
                byte pixelG = row[gIndex];
                byte pixelB = row[bIndex];

                if( Math.Abs(FindColorR - pixelR) > WithinDistanceByte && 
                    Math.Abs(FindColorG - pixelG) > WithinDistanceByte &&
                    Math.Abs(FindColorB - pixelB) > WithinDistanceByte )
                {
                    row[rIndex] = ReplaceColorR;
                    row[gIndex] = ReplaceColorG;
                    row[bIndex] = ReplaceColorB;
                }
                else
                {
                    row[rIndex] = FindColorR;
                    row[gIndex] = FindColorG;
                    row[bIndex] = FindColorB;
                }
            }
        }
        image.UnlockBits(imageData);
    }
```